# Setting MySQL table_cache variable

Tags: mysql, performance, tuning

Greetings,

I've set the table_cache variable in /etc/mysql/my.cnf on Ubuntu to 512, but the reported value is only 64. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I presume you restarted MySQL? And the line in /etc/mysql/my.cnf says "table_cache = 512"?

Comment: This is correct, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table_cache` increases the amount of file descriptors that mysqld requires.  This is a system limitation, which can also be limited in MySQL with the `open-files-limit` configuration option.

To see the current system wide limitation in Linux you can run `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`.  This can also be limited on a per-user basis using `ulimit -n`.

If file descriptors are not the issue and you configured the setting correctly, MySQL could be using a different my.cnf.  Look at the processlist, where the `--defaults-extra-file` could specify the cnf.  Also, if unspecified the `--datadir` is often where the my.cnf can live.

You could also search the filesystem for additional my.cnf files.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go. ( I'll vote this up when I have enough rep )

Comment: Assuming this addresses your issue @kobrien, you can click the check mark to accept the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I'll get to test this in the morning, I'll accept right afterwards if it works. :)

Comment: Still haven't gotten around to testing this. Don't worry, I haven't forgotten. :)